Who can access the FAA's Electronic Document Retrieval System?
I've used The FAA Aircraft Registration website to request aircraft records, which includes registraion records and forms 337.
I am now working on an airworthiness certificate for an import.  I received a checklist from the DAR, which includes the instruction "Download and review FAA EDRS files, 337s & STC's"
I've found the EDRS website, but it appears to require a login, and it is not obvious to me how I might create an account.  I suspect access to this site may be limited to FAA employees and designees.
I suspect what I need to do is to contact a DAR and ask them to pull the records on my behalf.  Am I on the right track here?  Are there others with access to this information?

I was able to get an answer from the DAR that I've been working with.  He informed me that the information retrievable by this system is the same as what is available from the aircraft registration office.
